# Is there a way to use rich:columnGroup in rich:extendedDataTable?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I got the task to convert one of our old tables, which was built with rich:dataTable into a rich:extendedDataTable. In the old tables we worked with rich:columnGroup to split the header into 2 rows. I know that rich:columnGroup does not work in combination with extendedDataTable. Is there maybe a workaround for this or even an alternative to columnGroup?
Thanks a lot

What it looked like with rich:dataTable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZnI.png)

How it currently looks like (I am still relatively at the beginning):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdrgw.png)

If needed I can provide the code but I only hava a simple rich:extendedDataTable with a few columns - each column is in this facet

```
<f:facet name="header">
```

I hope that works as a minimal example - its the first Column and I want to have the inputfeld under the text (Attributes like var probably need to be removed?):

```
      <rich:extendedDataTable
        id="#{_idTable}"
        value="#{_pagination.data}"
        var="_t"
        width="100%"
        rowClasses="tablerow-odd, tablerow-even">

          <c:if test="#{includeDefaultActionColumn}">
            <rich:column width="8%">
              <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText
                  value="#{messages['de.segal.baoss.module.numberrange.entity.NumberRangeName.ImpersonalNumber']}" />
              </f:facet>

            </rich:column>
          </c:if>

          <rich:column>
          <c:if test="#{!_disableFilter}">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <b:filterTable reRender="#{_idTable}Header1" key="accountNumber"
                pagination="#{_pagination}" />
            </f:facet>
          </c:if>
          <div class="row">
            <s:fragment rendered="#{reverseActionEnabled and _t.draft eq false and _t.bookingType eq 'IMPERSONAL'}">
              <div class="col-4" style="padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;">
                <b:confirmationButton id="#{_idTable}generateReverseTransaction"
                  value="#{messages['ui.common.yes']}"
                  buttonText="#{messages['invoicing.booking.generic.reversePosting']}"
              ajaxSingle="true"
                  messageText="#{e:messageForHtml('invoicing.booking.generic.reversePosting.confirmation')}"
                  headerText="#{messages['ui.common.confirm']}"
                  styleClass="col-12 w-icon undo" reRender="#{_idTable}Header1"
                  action="#{invoicing.genericBookingManager.generateReverseTransaction(_t, _pagination)}" >
                  <span class="tooltip">#{messages['invoicing.booking.generic.reversePosting.tooltip']}</span>
                </b:confirmationButton>
              </div>
            </s:fragment>
            <s:fragment rendered="#{establishActionEnabled and _t.draft}">
              <div class="col-4" style="padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;">
                <b:confirmationButton id="#{_idTable}establishAccountingTransaction"
                  value="#{messages['ui.common.yes']}"
                  immediate="true"
                  messageText="#{e:messageForHtml('invoicing.booking.generic.establishAccountingTransaction.confirmation')}"
                  headerText="#{messages['ui.common.confirm']}"
                  styleClass="col-12 w-icon lock_open" reRender="#{_idTable}Header1"
                  action="#{invoicing.accountingTransactionOverviewManager.establishAccountingTransaction(_t)}">
                  <span class="tooltip">#{messages['invoicing.booking.generic.establishAccountingTransaction.tooltip']}</span>
                </b:confirmationButton>
              </div>
            </s:fragment>
            <s:fragment rendered="#{deleteActionEnabled and _t.draft}">
              <div class="col-4" style="padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;">
                <b:confirmationButton id="#{_idTable}btnDeleteItem"
                  value="#{not empty _t.openItemTransferLog or not empty _t.accountingExportDate?messages['de.segal.baoss.module.invoicing.common.deleteAnyway']:messages['ui.common.delete']}" buttonText=""
                  cancelText="#{messages['ui.common.cancel']}"
                  ajaxSingle="true"
                  messageText="#{not empty _t.openItemTransferLog or not empty _t.accountingExportDate?e:messageForHtml('de.segal.baoss.module.invoicing.service.message.hintTransactionAlreadyExported'):messages['de.segal.baoss.platform.groupware.mail.delete']}"
                  headerText="#{messages['ui.common.confirm']}"
                  styleClass="col-12 w-icon w-icon-red cancel"
                  reRender="#{_idTable}Header1,idReceiptTable,massWorkflowPanel"
                  oncomplete="#{deleteActionOncomplete}"
                  action="#{_bean.deleteTransaction(_t)}">
                  <span class="tooltip">#{messages['ui.common.delete']}</span>
                </b:confirmationButton>
              </div>
            </s:fragment>
          </div>
        </rich:column>

      </rich:extendedDataTable>
```

I'm really sorry about the 2nd big part, I tried to shorten it but I don't know how far the fragments are "important" ... isn't it just a text field?.. Maybe you can tell me a little bit about that too? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is each column in a header facet?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. I'm just following the old code. But the old code also used subtables, maybe that's why there is a header separation? unfortunately I do not have much experience with JSF..

Comment: JSF is great... Good for business apps.But even for subtables... the column definitions in a header facet is weird. And next time do try to create a [mcve]  and post it. So we can see all possible errors at once.

Comment: I added the code example. I'm really sorry for writing in such generalities. I've been sitting on this ticket forever and I just can't get anywhere. The first year of apprenticeship is hard.

Comment: The columns are not in the facets here, other way around. And It seems like something CSS related. Investigate client-side in the html